# How to load wordpress function in custom url

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dashboard

I am creating custom dashboard but for login/register setup I used WordPress. After login user will redirect to my dashboard link, here is my code

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'dvs_admin_default_page');
function dvs_admin_default_page() {
  return '/user/dashboard.php';
}
```

But how I load wordpress function in my custom link, like if I want to run any wordpress function then how to call it isside custom php file.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_page()`. The `is_page()` function accepts page title, slug or id. [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

```
<?php 
if(is_page('myscript')) {
    include '/path/to/myscript.php';
}
?>
```